# Windows 2012 R2 RDS Black Blank Screen on login by admin or users in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, windows-server-2012-r2

I am a Windows Sysadmin running a set of Windows 2012 R2 servers on GCP that were deployed via Itopia which is a Google Cloud partner that orchestrates the deployment of Windows 2012 R2 servers on Google cloud for the sole purpose of running IAAS Windows RDS servers on GCP.

Sporadically when users or myself (domain admin) logs into the RDS session host the login appears as normal and seems to pass user login stage but then the desktop experience shows up as a blank black screen with no start menu or explorer as you would normally see logging into a windows desktop experience on RDS.

Has anyone else experienced this issue on Windows RDS or Windows RDS on GCP?  I know that GCP does not install display adapters into their servers so it is impossible to get to a graphical UI as an administrator to see what is going on with this server.

I'm not very familiar with the Google Cloud Shell but I understand there might be some commands there to check on services or other parts of the O/S health.

In my case I believe it is a RDS service that is failing and needs to be restarted but is stuck for some reason.  With the lack of a console it is difficult to troubleshoot.

Any suggestion on how to best tackle this?

Thanks

Comment: GCP windows machine are like any other windows server and you can use RDP protocol to connect to them if firewall and connectivity allows you. Check your firewall rule, if you see a back screen after logging in, just wait few minutes, depending on the machine type, the first time it might take a while for your server to be ready. I created one machine yesterday and I got out of the black screen in 1-2 minutes. If the problem persists, check this page about how to troubleshoot the issue: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-rdp

Comment: What do you mean " it is impossible to get to a graphical UI". Windows Servers on GCP has a desktop except for the core versions. How much memory does your VM have? Low memory can cause RDP desktops to not display correctly.

Comment: 13GB of RAM and 2 VCPUs.

Answer (score 1):

You might have install the Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter Core instead of the Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter one. the difference between these, there is no desktop in Server Core, by design. you can review [the windows document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/server-core/what-is-server-core) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Also posting as answer as I don't have rep, sorry.
GCP vms do have a console you can access, will be CLI only but very handy for trouble shooting.  From the instances page, click edit, right below the remote access options check "Enable connecting to serial ports" and then save.  Then you should have the option to Connect to serial console at the top under Remote access. for windows I believe it's serial port 2.  When you connect you'll enter "CMD" enter, then shift+esc, then enter, and you'll be prompted for your creds.  no delete/backspace so type it in correctly or start over.  Once authenticated you should be at the Windows CLI prompt
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console